# How should I find this first-integral of a functional?

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

Let $0<a<b$. Consider the functional $$S[y]=\int_{a}^{b}x^5(y'^2-\frac{2}{3}y^3)dx$$ Prove that a first-integral of $S[y]$ is $$4x^5yy'+x^6(y'^2+\frac{2}{3}y^3)=c,$$ where $c$ is constant, stating any theorems that you use.

---

I know that the Euler-Lagrange equation for $S[y]$ is $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{5}{x}\frac{dy}{dx}+y^2=0$$ but how should I prove this? Does it has anything to do with this equation: $$f-y'\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}=\text{constant}~?$$

If so, then what's $f, y', \frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let
$$
g(x):=4x^5yy'+x^6\left(y'^2+\frac{2}{3}y^3\right). \tag{1}
$$
Compute $g'(x)$ and use the Euler-Lagrange equation
$y''=-\frac{5}{x}y'-y^2$ to simplify terms containing $y''$. If you do it correctly, you will find that $g'(x)=0$, hence $g(x)=c$.

Remark: The equation $f-y'\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}=C$, known as [Beltrami identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami_identity), is true for functionals of the form
$$
S[y]=\int_a^bf[x,y(x),y'(x)]\,dx \tag{2}
$$
if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0$. That's not the case for the functional in your question.

Comment: Although I got this problem now, but I still want to know why did you express $g(x) :=4x^5yy'+x^6(y'^2+\frac{2}{3}y^3)$ instead of $g(x)=4x^5yy'+x^6(y'^2+\frac{2}{3}y^3)$? What does $:=$ indicate/mean in calculus of variations?

Comment: The symbol ":=" is not specific to calculus of variations. It means "is defined as".

Comment: Great. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

1. Given an explicit quantity, it is easy to verify whether or not it is conserved (as a function of time $x$), cf. Gonçalo's answer.
2. If we don't already know the explicit form of the conserved quantity/first integral, we can find it using [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem). This is what we will do in this answer.
3. It is easy to see that OP's functional
   $$ S[y;a,b] ~=~S[\tilde{y};\tilde{a},\tilde{b}]$$
   has an exact symmetry
   $$\tilde{y}(\tilde{x})~=~\lambda^{\color{red}{2}}y(x), \qquad
   \tilde{x}~=~\lambda^{\color{red}{-1}}x, $$
   where $\lambda> 0$ is a positive parameter.
4. Since OP's Lagrangian is $$L~=~x^5(\dot{y}^2-\frac{2}{3}y^3),$$
   the corresponding momentum and energy are
   $$ p~:=~\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}~=~2x^5\dot{y}$$
   and $$h~:=~p\dot{y}-L~=~x^5(\dot{y}^2+\frac{2}{3}y^3),$$
   respectively. The corresponding Noether charge
   $$ Q~=~\color{red}{2y}p - \color{red}{(-x)}h~=~4x^5y\dot{y}+x^6(\dot{y}^2+\frac{2}{3}y^3)$$
   is OP's sought-for conserved quantity/first integral.
5. For more details, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41265/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Comment: This is something new. Thank you!